# Warning: unlink(D:\Temp/......tmp): Permission denied

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, permission-denied, tmp

I'm migrating my website wordpress on server 1and1 
but I have this error

[image]

---

**Warning 1**

> Warning: unlink(D:\Temp/2457288785706f20cd0bab.tmp): Permission denied in E:\kunden\homepages\13\d228433126\www\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 1776

```
        // check tmp file for read/write capabilities
        $should_delete_tmp_file = !file_exists( $path );
        $f = @fopen( $path, 'a' );
        if ( $f === false )
            return false;
        fclose( $f );
        if ( $should_delete_tmp_file )
 1776   unlink( $path );
            return true;
         }
```

---

**Warning 2**

> Warning: fopen(D:\Temp/custom-yKSRXm.tmp): failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:\kunden\homepages\13\d228433126\www\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-filesystem-ftpext.php on line 117

```
    public function get_contents( $file ) {
    $tempfile = wp_tempnam($file);
117 $temp = fopen($tempfile, 'w+');

    if ( ! $temp )
        return false;

    if ( ! @ftp_fget($this->link, $temp, $file, FTP_BINARY ) )
        return false;
```

Someone Help !!

Comment: It looks like you have no permission to write on the system, check if the user have the permission for the web service.

Comment: i already checked it i have all the permission but still the same problem , i think on this server is for windows iis and his not work probably with wordpress !!?

Comment: I have the same issue, I think it is related to the unit (drive) is not C:\ I have read you have to create a virtualdirectory to that drive and give the IIS user write permissions. I did that but still not able to write. More ideas?